# Magento Catalog Product Images are not showing

Tags: magento-2.0.2

Magento2 Catalog Product Images are not showing. All was working good on **localhost**.

But when i move all files on server after that product images are not showing on frontend.

Please check this link http://kiegeszitoshop.hu/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html

Can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 3):

You need to regenerate cache image :

Navigate **System->Cache Management** under **Additional Cache Management** click on Flush Catalog Images Cache
clear your cache and refresh the page now you are able to see product image.

Comment: Not worked ! For your knowledge cache already disabled

Comment: have you flushed your magento cache ??

Comment: Ya ! I run php magento `cache:flush`

Comment: Working 1.http://kiegeszitoshop.hu/pub/media/catalog/product/m/j/mj04-black_main.jpg"

2. not working :http://kiegeszitoshop.hu/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/j/mj04-black_main.jpg  it generating 404 errors

Comment: BUt if go to home page http://kiegeszitoshop.hu/ YOu can see there already have products which is showing

Comment: Delete your browser cache nothing is showing on home page

Comment: Yes may be some problem came.. I need to check